# Adding Image to ListView - SQL Server database - image doesn't appear

Tags: listview, sql-server-2000, imagelist

I'm working on a dynamic listview from SQL Server 2000 database, and I need to add image on it. I already added `ImageList` control to my form, and set the `ListView` property to `LargeIcon`, `SmallImageList` as the `ImageList`.

I do not know how to add image on the listview. Here is my code and I don't know what's wrong with it, though it shows the data from database, only the image is not appearing:

```
Public Sub PopulateListView_Images(ByVal lv As ListView, ByVal cmd As SqlCommand, ByVal myImageList As ImageList)
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    Dim ds As New DataSet

    ds.Reset()
    da = New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
    da.Fill(ds)
    'Fill Method
    lv.Columns.Clear()
    lv.Items.Clear()

    lv.SmallImageList = myImageList

    'Fill Listview
    Dim c As DataColumn
    For Each c In ds.Tables(0).Columns
        'adding names of columns as Listview columns                
        Dim h As New ColumnHeader
        h.Text = c.ColumnName
        h.Width = 60
        lv.Columns.Add(h)
    Next
    Dim dt As DataTable = ds.Tables(0)
    Dim str(ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count) As String

    'adding Datarows as listview Grids
    Dim rr As DataRow
    For Each rr In dt.Rows
        For col As Integer = 0 To ds.Tables(0).Columns.Count - 1
            str(col) = rr(col).ToString()
        Next
        Dim ii As New ListViewItem(str)
        lv.Items.Add(ii)
        'showing the number of records still added
    Next
End Sub
```

In this code, only the data is showing but no image. I tried adding :

```
lv.Items(0).ImageKey = 0
```